# Does typedef in C/C++ really create a NEW type by combining the compound type (e.g. int*)?

Tags: c++, c, types, grammar, typedef

recently I found `typedef` in my code works really different than what I proposed. An example like this:

```
typedef int *ptype;
ptype v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
```

The result: both v1 and v2 were defined as a pointer to `int` type. But if you simply replace `ptype` by `int *` in the second sentence as `int *v1 = 0, v2 = 0;` or `int* v1 = 0, v2 =0;`, only v1 will be the pointer and v2 is normal `int`. It seems `typedef` does not do a simple replacement. What's more, when it comes to complicate modifier like:

```
typedef int *ptype;
const ptype v3 = 0;
```

The result will be: v3 is a `const` pointer, not a pointer to the `const` int if we write `const int *v3 = 0;`. In the above code `const` stands as the modifier to the whole `ptype`, not the `int` inside `ptype`. Thus it really looks like `typedef` combines the compound type `int*` and creates a new type.

However, the authoritative C/C++ reference website [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) says "typedef does not create different types. It only creates synonyms of existing types." so I was really confused and hope someone can help explain the behavior of `typedef`. Thanks!

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. cplusplus.com is not authoritative.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think you're spreading FUD: cplusplus.com used to have a lot of defects in the documentation, but they ironed out a lot of them by now. I don't think cplusplus.com is such a bad reference these days.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe That doesn't mean it's authoritative.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Actually, I purposedly did not mention any of the history of cplusplus.com because I have not yet looked at it since the relatively recent brush up. The authoritative reference is the ISO C++ standard, and the official site is http://isocpp.org.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe ... by saying that it's not authoritative?

Comment: @melpomene: It seems to me he got all hung up on the 'authoritative' part (quite obviously the OP doesn't know what that word actually means in this context), I think what he is *actually* communicating is that cplusplus.com is not a good source of information on C/C++ (such as the behaviour of `typedef`), because it's "not authoritative".

Comment: For the benefit of anyone that hasn't noticed it, there is very little to get hung up on my comment besides the "authoritative" part. All that is left beyond that is: a bunch of "no"s, and regular sentence scaffolding. Which one should get hung up on, then? I think we should get hung up on my sentence scaffolding. I promise I will write "isn't" instead of "is not" next time. (TL;DR I find it very insulting when people insist in reading in my words something I have not written.)

Comment: Hi R. Martinho Fernandes and Frerich Raabe, thanks for your comments. I used to believe cplusplus.com is authoritative since usually it ranks higher in Google search results. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe - Here comes the problem - how "authoritative" the one should be to decide what is authoritative)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be insulting. I guess I really read too much into your comment, I've just been in a few arguments lately where language lawyers were nitpicking about what things like 'defined' or 'standard' mean, totally confusing the OP who obviously just wanted to know how a little C++ keyword works. I apologize. :-/

Comment: On a side note: The way of writing `const` left to the typename is an oddity of the C language. Technically `const` is left associative, i.e. it works on what's *left* of it. Now if const happens to be the first token in a statement it gets silently rearranged right after the first type token. That's why when writing `const ptype` makes this a const pointer, since the const is "rewritten" to come after the pointer classifier (`*`).

Comment: If you look into my own code you'll find no single `const` to start a statement. Heck I've even added a code checker that won't let me commit changes into the VCS should I have accidently written `const` at the start of a statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Synonym" does not mean "text replacement". `ptype` is not literally expanded to `int *` by the preprocessor or anything.

What it means is that you can do things like:

```
typedef int *ptype;
ptype a;
int *b;

a = b;   // OK
```

The assignment is valid because `ptype` and `int *` are the same type; there is no type conversion or cast required.

`typedef` simply lets you give a new name to an existing type. But that name combines every aspect of the existing type into an indivisible entity, such that e.g. `ptype a, b;` is equivalent to `ptype a; ptype b;` (and `const ptype` means "const pointer-to-int" because `ptype` means "pointer-to-int").

In other words, the new *names* created by `typedef` behave like built-in keywords as far as declaring things goes, but the actual *types* represented by those names are the same.

Comment: "indivisible entity" - got it. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Also, it is not possible to overload functions, or templates, based on discriminating by typedef.

Comment: @PeterWood Yeah, that would be like overloading based on e.g. `signed int` vs. `int` or `const double` vs. `double const`. They're just different names for the same underlying type.

Answer (score 2):

When cplusplus.com says that `typedef` doesn't create a new type, what they mean is that anywhere where you can use a value of `ptype` you can also use a value of type `int*` and vice-verse. So if you define a function that takes a `ptype` parameter, you can pass it an `int*` without any conversions being necessary.

That does not mean that a `typedef` is implemented as purely textual substitution like a `#define` would be.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to C89, section 3.5, here's the reason that `ptype v1 = 0, v2 = 0;` is not equivalent to `int *v1 = 0, v2 = 0;`. Later versions of C and C++ were informed by C89 and are essentially the same in this respect.

In `ptype v1 = 0, v2 = 0;`, `ptype` is the "declaration-specifiers", and `v1 = 0, v2 = 0` is the "init-declarator-list". Specifically, `ptype` is a "type-specifier" and even more specifically it's a "typedef-name". So, we're declaring two variables (`v1` and `v2`) both of which have type `ptype`, which is another name for `int*`.

In `int* v1 = 0, v2 = 0`, `int*` is *not* the "declaration-specifiers", because that consists of a series of "type-specifier", "storage-class-specifier" and "type-qualifier". You can look up each of those in turn, but all put together they amount to a whole list of keywords like `static` or `const`, built-in type names, plus typedef and enum names and struct/union specifiers. They *don't* include the `*`, which is part of the syntax for a compound type. So in this case `int` is the "declaration-specifiers and `*v1 = 0, v2 = 0` is the "init-declarator list". Once we break down the grammar of the "init-declarator list", the `*` applies only to `v1`, not to `v2`. That's why it defines one `int*` and one `int`.

Similarly you could write `ptype *v1 = 0, v2 = 0;`, which would define one `pytpe*` and one `ptype`. That is to say, one `int**` and one `int*`.

The grammar for `const int *` vs `const ptype` works out to a similar result -- in the former the `const` "type-qualifier" applies to the `int` but in the latter it applies to `ptype`.