# Is unsigned int a `simple-type-specifier`

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer

The reason I'm asking this is because, notwithstanding the fact that the title for [Table 11](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#tab:simple.type.specifiers) is *simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify*, the grammar production [simple-type-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1) doesn't mention this combination of types, as a *simple-type-specifier*.  So is `unsigned int` a simple-type-specifier?

**Edit**: <strike>I don't think the answer given to the [aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977808) is correct. If that was true, one would not be able to say that the declaration `void* operator new(std::size_t);` is a *declaration* as defined in [[dcl.dcl]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1), as `size_t` is `typedef` defined (in my system) as `unsigned int`. To show this assertion, i.e., that `void* operator new(std::size_t);` is a *declaration*, I almost sure we need the fact that an `unsigned int` **is** a *simple-type-specifier*.</strike>. <strike>I was wrong. There is no problem in saying that `void* operator new(std::size_t);` is a *declaration*, if we use the definition of *type-name* given in [[dcl.type.simple]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1)</strike>. I think I was right the first time, except for the wrong example. That is, I believe that `unsigned int` **has to be** a *[simple-type-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1)*, otherwise one would not be able to say that `void f(unsigned int);` is a [*declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#1).

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit type conversion (functional notation) with simple-type-specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977808/explicit-type-conversion-functional-notation-with-simple-type-specifier)

Comment: The `typedef` is a different question, because [it creates a new name for the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334317/does-typedef-in-c-c-really-create-a-new-type-by-combining-the-compound-type-e) and is not a simple textual replacement. `typedef unsigned int size_t;` is not at all the same as `#define size_t unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `unsigned int` is not a simple-type-specifier.  If you read the [preceding paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#2) you have

> Table 11 summarizes the **valid combinations** of simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, while both `unsigned` and `int` are listed in [paragraph 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1) as simple-type-specifiers the combination of the two is not, but it is a valid type.

Comment: I had to withdraw  my acceptance to your answer, as I firmly believe that `unsigned int` is a *simple-type-specifier*. See again my edit above.

Comment: @Alexander Paragraph one clearly list all simple-type-specifiers that exist in C++.  `unsigned int` is not among it.

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/kUzte2ECDJ4/7vwZ1rAoBwAJ). Thanks.